# Fluentd events to Splunk

Tags: openshift, splunk, fluentd

I need send some events from fluentd to splunk.

I read this: https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_splunk    ,  https://www.fluentd.org/dataoutputs,   so I decided that it is possible. But I don't understand how can I configure it.

I have 
-splunk
-openshift with 'logging' project where I have the EFK (elasticsearch, fluend, kibana) stack

Now I don't understand where I can configure "out_splunk" plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify `/etc/fluentd/fluentd.conf` file to include the output clause as described in the splunk plugin [readme](https://github.com/parolkar/fluent-plugin-splunk).
If you provide your docker-compose.yaml or at least the fluentd image you are using I can further guide you to the location of the file and the changes it should include.

Comment: how to configure oitput in fluentd,  if i have 3 splunk ip's ?

Comment: That's kind of a separate question but you can use multiple destinations in fluentd by choosing @copy in your match statement and then specifying multiple <store> tags.

Comment: no i want forward every log to splunk cluster (3 servers)  , like elasticsearch cluster

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how splunk clusters work but with Elasticsearch you write to the http endpoint you decided on (which resolves to one of the nodes in your cluster) and that node will propagate the data to sufficient nodes so the replication factor would be satisfied. Anyway this is far beyond the scope of Fluentd.